# How to periodically send failure messages from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to access one host address from the AWS Lambda.If it fails, i have to send the mail.The issue is i have to combine all the failure messages for a period and send to the mail is.What technology i can use for this?I can't use DLQ as i don't want to capture all the failure messages from the Lambda

Comment: What does it mean "it fails"? Fails how? Heath check fails, or AWS-caused hardware failure? What are these " failure messages"? From your application?

Comment: It failed to get response from an host address.For example,the host  server is down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be possibly more than one option.

1. Using Dead Letter Queue for Lambda and process the queue messages once you hit your trigger. See: [AWS Lambda Supports Dead Letter Queues](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/12/aws-lambda-supports-dead-letter-queues/)
2. Store errors in a database like DynamoDB and scan once the period trigger is activated.

Comment: Regarding the Option 1 :Actually i don't want to capture all errors from the Lambda.Just one error type(where host is not reachable).

Comment: @SandeepM There are many tools for observability to look for specific errors. I would recommend try looking for something which is working for all your infrastructure but not focus on a single lambda failure handling. If you provide a concrete code there could be a better solution.